# GRUB "no such partition" Dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, grubrescue

I tried to set up a dual boot for my Windows 7 and Ubuntu using live USB, but I get a `no such partition` error when I try to load from my hard drive after the installation.

Tried using the [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), but problem persists. <strike>Log of boot-repair is at http://paste.ubuntu.com/10561552/</strike>

EDIT: After I get the message `Loading operating system`, on the black screen, I get `error: no such partition` and then I immediately go into the `GRUB>` command line. I'd assume it goes before the Grub menu? It does not refer to any partition. `ls` command `hd(0), hd(0,msdos1), hd(0,msdos2)`.

Comment: At which point during boot do you see that error message? Before or after the Grub menu? Does the say which partition it refers to?

Comment: @DavidFoerster, after I get the message "Loading operating system", on the black screen, I get "error: no such partition" and then I immediately go into the GRUB> command line. I'd assume it goes before the Grub menu? It does not refer to any partition. ls command returns hd(0), hd(0,msdos1), hd(0,msdos2)

Comment: Apparently Grub doesn't find the extended partition 6 with Linux and its own stuff. Can you please run `insmod part_msdos`, `insmod ext2`, `ls`, `set root=hd0,msdos6`, `ls` in that order on the Grub rescue shell, that you mention, and post their output?

Comment: @DavidFoerster, I still get same output of "hd(0), hd(0,msdos2), hd(0,msdos1)".

Comment: That's really weird for Grub not to detect extended MBR partitions. Does it help if you fix the order of the partition tables with `fdisk` (see section 7 of http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/09/linux-fdisk/)?

Comment: @DavidFoerster, fixing of order of the partition tables doesn't seem to help, either. I'll try moving extended partitions to the start of the HDD. It seemed to help [this guy](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123214/grub-doesnt-see-ext4-partitions-error-no-such-partition)

Comment: Good idea! In that case it should be enough to have the `/boot` partition somewhere more at the beginning of the hard drive, if that's more suitable for you.

Comment: @DavidFoerster, moving Linux partition to the "beginning" of HDD did help after all, thank you for you help!

Comment: Good to hear. It would be good, if you convert your comment with the solution to a proper answer and accept it. Drop me a line and I'll vote it up, if it's any good.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the disk is too big for the BIOS on my system, so GRUB will not find the Linux boot partition and will create an error message.

Should your Linux partition be visible when running `fdisk -l /dev/sda` or using `boot-repair` from, say, Live USB, but is *not* visible when running `ls` from `GRUB>` rescue shell, you might have a similar problem. In that case, moving your Linux partition to the beginning of the drive, using GParted or any other software, and then making your Linux partition there might help.

Similar problem presented [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123214/grub-doesnt-see-ext4-partitions-error-no-such-partition).